# Value keeps incrementing even though loop has terminated, why?

Tags: c++

I use a double called delta and use that to turn off an LCD if delta is larger than the timeout threshold. Once that happens, delta is supposed to set to 0 and then other parts of the program run. However, delta continues to increment and I'm not sure why.

This is causing a problem because delta is used to determine if the device should "sleep". So when I try to wake up the device via button click, delta is always way past the timeout threshold and the device immediately goes back to sleep.

Any thoughts as to why? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <M5StickC.h>

double BUTTON_PRESS_NEXT_PRESS_TIME= .5; //Time in seconds
double MINIMUM_BUTTON_PRESS_TIME = .05; //Time in seconds
int BUTTON_PRESS_SLEEP = 3; //Time in seconds
int SCREEN_TIMEOUT = 5;
int count;

static int pressCount = 1;
static int nextPress= 1;

static bool buttonIsPressed;

void setup(void) {
  buttonIsPressed = false;
  M5.begin();
  M5.Lcd.setRotation(0);
  M5.Lcd.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE, TFT_BLACK);

  // Datum is middle centre
  M5.Lcd.setTextDatum(MC_DATUM);
  M5.Axp.ScreenBreath(100);
  
  updateScreen();      
}

void updateScreen() {
   char tmp[12];
  
  // Datum is middle centre
  M5.Lcd.setTextDatum(MC_DATUM);
  M5.Lcd.drawString(dtostrf(pressCount,4,0,tmp), 80,60,6);
  M5.Lcd.drawString(dtostrf(nextPress,3,0,tmp), 80,100,6);
}

static void evaluatePress(double d) {
   // Evaluate press 
  if (d >= BUTTON_PRESS_NEXT_PRESS_TIME) {
    nextPress++;
    pressCount = 1;
        
    if (nextPress == 19) {
      nextPress= 1;
    }
  }
  else if (d >= MINIMUM_BUTTON_PRESS_TIME && d < BUTTON_PRESS_NEXT_PRESS_TIME) {
    pressCount++;
  }
    
  updateScreen();
}

void sleepLoop() {
  bool bIsPressed = false;
  Serial.println("Sleep 1");
  while(1) {
    Serial.println("Sleep 2");
    if (digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == LOW && !bIsPressed) {
      bIsPressed = true;
    }

    if (digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == HIGH && bIsPressed){
      Serial.println("BREAKY BREAKY");
      M5.Axp.ScreenBreath(100);

      break;
    }
  }
}

void awakeLoop() {  
  double delta;
  double old_time;
  double current_time;

  Serial.println("Awake 1");
  
  while(1) {
    Serial.println("Awake 2");
     //Calculate delta time
    old_time = current_time;
    current_time =  millis();
    delta = delta + (current_time - old_time)/1000;

    if (digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == LOW && !buttonIsPressed) {
      buttonIsPressed = true; 
      delta = 0;
    }

    if(digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == HIGH && buttonIsPressed) {
      buttonIsPressed = false;
      evaluatePress(delta);
      delta=0;
    }
 
    if(delta > SCREEN_TIMEOUT && !buttonIsPressed) {
      Serial.println(delta);
      Serial.print("BREAK AWAKE");
      Serial.println(M5.Axp.ScreenBreath(0));
      count = 0;
      break;
    }
    else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  delta = 0;
}

void loop() {
  awakeLoop();
  sleepLoop();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's a crazy way of doing a screen timeout. You don't need `delta` and you certainly don't want it to be a `double`...  Just record `current_time = millis()` when an action happens and break when `(millis() - current_time) > 5000`.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko. I've stripped out some code so that the question focuses more directly on the problem. I think I can do what you suggested though and will give it a try. What's wrong with a double?

Comment: @Kyle `double` needs floating point operations for every calculation, which the Arduino does not support in its hardware. Thus this has to be done in software, which is very computation expensive. So a general rule is, to only use a floating point type (`float` or `double`), when it is really necessary. `millis()` uses `unsigned long`, so why not using the same for the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```cpp
void awakeLoop(){  
  double delta;
  // The rest of the function body...
  delta = 0;
}
```

delta is being defined as a variable local to the function `awakeLoop()`
and with automatic storage. This means the variable is created whenever
the program enters the function, is *not* implicitly initialized, and is
destroyed when the function returns.

The last statement `delta = 0;` has no effect, as it is setting a
variable that is going to be destroyed right away. The compiler most
likely got rid of it.

You most likely want the variable to retain its value across invocations
of the function. For this to be the case, it has to be either global
(defined outside the function) or local with the `static` qualifier. In
both cases, it will have static storage, i.e. its lifetime will be the
whole program run. Also, if you fail to explicitly initialize it, the
compiler will implicitly initialize it to zero.

Comment: Thanks @Edgar Bonet. The problem that I'm having is that delta does *not* actually get set to 0 or destroyed. I know that I shouldn't/don't need to set delta to 0 at the end of the loop, but I added that line because the program is not acting as I'd expect. The line that prints out delta, right below "Brake awake" always prints out a value that I would expect if the loop were to run continually.

Comment: @Kyle: That value is meaningless, as `delta` has not been initialized. Whether it matches your expectations or not is just chance, and you should not count on it.